# Dashboard resources

Tags: dashboard

We are developing a dashboard for a web application and I wondered if there was a web resource of any do's and don't of dashboard design? I know there are some good books on this subject (which I have ordered), but I need to produce something ASAP.

Comment: I would highly recommend the articles written by Stephen Few. Some are more at a high level design detail, but there are many with good examples to illustrate the concepts and ideas that he talks about.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have found some links to some online resources and books. Hope it helps...

https://cw.sdn.sap.com/cw/docs/DOC-142813

http://www.perceptualedge.com/library.php#Books

http://apogeehk.com/archives/dashboards/

http://www.enterprise-dashboard.com/

http://www.boxesandarrows.com/view/enhancing-dashboard

http://www.information-management.com/issues/20050901/1035522-1.html

http://dashboardspy.wordpress.com/

Comment: Thanks will take a look now. The Stephen Few books are the ones I have on order, so will get round to them later this week.